# Assigning a Concatenated String to Variable in R

Tags: r

I have a case where I am trying to assign a concatenated string to a variable. Yet whenever I check the variables value, it is empty. My reason for concatenation is so I have the strings occurring on separate lines:

My desired output should be a variable which holds data in the format:

```
OUTLET:  KIBO PHARMACY 
OWNER:  MARIAM 
MOBILE:  765816927
```

I have tried:

```
row.popup <- cat(paste("OUTLET: ",row.outlet,"\n"),
                         paste("OWNER: ", row.owner,"\n"),
                         paste("MOBILE: ", row.mobileNo))
```

The above does not assign the concatenated string to the variable. I also tried:

```
row.popup <- paste(cat("OUTLET: ",row.outlet,"\n"),
                         cat("OWNER: ", row.owner,"\n"),
                         cat("MOBILE: ", row.mobileNo))
```

This too does not assign the concatenated string to the variable.

Any advice?

Comment: R is not C++. The dot has no meaning here, you aren't accessing any class members with `row.outlet` etc. The data needs to be stored otherwise, for instance in a list.

Comment: @RHertel I am aware, and am not using C++ nor Java style dot notation, am just following [style guides](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml#identifiers), it should have no effect on code logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessarily what you asked for, as this is just a string, but will display according to your expectations:

```
> row.popup <- paste("OUTLET: KIBO PHARMACY",'OWNER: MARIAM', "MOBILE:  765816927", sep="\n")
> cat(row.popup)
OUTLET: KIBO PHARMACY
OWNER: MARIAM
MOBILE:  765816927
```

Answer (score 0):

the data

```
row.outlet <- "KIBO PHARMACY"
row.owner <- "MARIAM"
row.mobileNo <- 765816927
```

you can try:

```
cat(paste(" OUTLET: ",row.outlet), "\n",
    paste("OWNER: ",row.owner), "\n",
    paste("MOBILE: ",row.mobileNo))
```